# Post JSON to a REST service and then iterate it

Tags: python, json, flask

i am having the following issue. I am trying to post a JSON object to a REST service that i have and then iterate it so as to do some database operations. I am getting the object in the REST in the code below but i cannot understand how to use it. I thought that 'data' is a String object and i can do a json.loads(data) but this wont work.

```
data = request.stream.read()
```

I am trying to achieve something like

```
for dat in data:
    result = dat['someJsonAttribute']
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"?  Do you get an error? What is the error? Are the results just wrong? Please be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

How do you post your data? you should include proper mimetype/encoding in your request. after that, you can read uploaded json from [`request.json`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.json) as if it were a python dictionary.